# How to show a user's favourites on a profile page using Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm relatively new to Django and am attempting to build a website where a user can view products and favourite them. I then want the user to be able to login and see their list of favourites.
FYI I've largely been using/following this django-blog tutorial to create this: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLCC34OHNcOtr025c1kHSPrnP18YPB-NFi

I currently have two apps setup; `Products` and `Customers`. In the `Products` app I have a model called `Product` with a field `likes` which is a ManytoMany field. I've got the like/unlike button all setup, but I'm just a bit confused about how to actually pull all the liked products attached to a user. Any help much appreciated! Code below...

Product model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    main_image = CloudinaryField('image', default='placeholder')
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(default="", null=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(default='placeholder', blank=True, max_length=1000)
    colours = models.TextField(default='Ivory', blank=True, max_length=500)
    sizes_avail = models.TextField(default='Enquire in store', blank=True, max_length=500)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blog_post')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_name
```

Customer model:

```
lass Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_pic = CloudinaryField('image', default='placeholder')
    date_of_wedding = models.DateField(default='2024-12-31')
    website_url = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home')
```

Views to like/unilike product:

```
def LikeView(request, pk):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=request.POST.get('product_id'))
    liked = False
    if product.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        product.likes.remove(request.user)
        liked = False
    else:
        product.likes.add(request.user)
        liked = True
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('product_details', args=[str(pk)]))
```

```
class ProductDetails(generic.DetailView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'product_details.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductDetails, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        data = get_object_or_404(Product, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        liked = False
        if data.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True
        context['liked'] = liked
        return context
```

HTML to like products:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <form action="{% url 'like_post' product.pk %}" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}

                    {% if liked %}
                        <button type="submit", name="product_id", value="{{ product.id }}", class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Remove from Favourites</button>
                    {% else %}
                        <button type="submit", name="product_id", value="{{ product.id }}", class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm">Add to Favourites</button>
                    {% endif %}
                    
                </form>
            {% else %}
                <p><em><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a> to save this dress to your Favourites</em></p>
            {% endif %}
```

Comment: Use reverse lookup https://stackoverflow.com/a/4881840/13773284